# Can I change the way ReSharper generates properties?

Tags: resharper

Is it possible to change the way that Resharper formats properties?

**I don't like:**

```
public string Foo 
{
    get 
    {
        return bar;
    }
    set 
    {
        bar = value;
    }
}
```

**I like:**

```
public string Foo 
{
    get { return bar; }
    set { bar = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You sure can, just go to Resharper > Options > Languages > C# > Formatting Style 
and tick "place simple property/indexer/event declaration on a single line"

**Updated for Resharper 8.2**:
Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Other > Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) Although in 4.5 its ReSharper > Options -> Languages > C# > Formating Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Other > Place simple accessor on single line.

Comment: Resharper 8.2
Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Other > Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the code expansion template to produce a property, you can update the template in the ReSharper Settings at: `ReSharper >> Live Templates >> Predefined Templates >> C# >> prop`.

If you're referring to the code produced by refactoring commands, I don't believe it's configurable. However, you may be able to run `Code Cleanup` and have it reformat.